# Update Urls in MVC 3 during json Request

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having a default page Controller like

> http://localhost/Test/Index.mvc/Index

I have a div which has nested drop-down's. on my last drop-down using jquery Ajax  i call a action method GetTime( string temp 1, string temp 2).But my url is still the same as above and it never changes

I need the url to change to

> http://localhost/Test/Index.mvc/Time?temp1=10&temp2=20

I added a new route map in global.ascx

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Test",
       "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
       new {controller ="Index", action="GetTime",id=" "});
```

when i use firebug to debug the urls are perfectly fine and i get the desired results but i need the urls to change for the case of bookmarking.

Thanks,
Pawan

Comment: Why do you have **.mvc** in your URLs?

Comment: I development enviornment is Windows XP SP2 + iis 6. When it goes to production it would be removed.  The enviornment is Windows Server 2008 and iis 7

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are using jQuery and Ajax to invoke the action.  That means that it's happening client-side.  The [only way to update the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) is to actually redirect to that URL.  You can't modify it, and nothing you do client-side short of the redirect is going to do any good.

In other words, you need to either:

1. Use `Html.ActionLink()`
2. Use a form + `<input type="submit" />`
3. Use javascript: `window.location = @Url.Action(...);`

Keep in mind that if you use option three, your action will execute all over again if you are still performing that ajax call -- probably not what you want.

Comment: I just tired to use the <%=Url.Action(...)%> without the window.location but it did not update the URL. Can you suggest what could be the best way to achieve this result or some kind of an example.

Comment: @Pawan, why did you try it "without the `window.location`"?  If you are still under the misapprehension that you can modify the URL without reloading the page then please desist. :)  That is categorically impossible.